# Definition of sequential compactness - Whats wrong with this alternation?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

The definition of sequential compactness:

A set $A$ in a metric space is sequentially compact if every sequence of elements of A has a convergent subsequence whose limit lies in $A$.

This alternation is wrong. Why?

A set $A$ in a metric space is sequentially compact if every converging sequence of elements of A has a limit that lies in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is the right one to define sequential compactness of a set. The second definition is *not an alternative* one. It is the definition of a sequentially closed set $A$.
The second pseudo-definition can not guarantee compactness. Take for instance $X= \mathbf R$ and let $A\subset X$ be an unbounded set.

Comment: Thanks! On the other hand: Is every sequentially compact set sequentially closed?

Comment: @stollenm A sequentially compact subset of a Hausdorff space is sequentially closed, as limits of convergent sequences are unique.